# Query does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function in UNION query

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions

I am doing a Union Query to add together the results of two separate queries that give me data from two different fiscal periods, to get a rolling 12 months number. 
I get the message "Your query does not include the specified expression "Report_Header" as part of an aggregate function".  I have read that the field needs to be included in a GROUP BY statement at the end, but when I add the field from either query or with both queries as shown below I still get the message.  Help?  I'm not a programmer, I'm an Access user, so I need to simple please :).

```
SELECT [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB].Report_Header,
       Sum([JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB].SumOfCASES) AS CASES,
       Sum([JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB].SumOfPurchases) AS PURCHASES
FROM [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB]

UNION ALL

SELECT [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2].Report_Header,
       Sum([JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2].SumOfCASES) AS CASES,
       Sum([JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2].SumOfPurchases) AS PURCHASES
FROM [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2]
GROUP BY [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB].Report_Header,
         [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2].Report_Header
```

Thanks!

Comment: The GROUP BY applies to the second select only.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want directly in MS Access. One common option is to put the `UNION ALL` into a view and use that for the aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate both subqueries:

```
SELECT [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB].Report_Header,
       Sum([JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB].SumOfCASES) AS CASES,
       Sum([JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB].SumOfPurchases) AS PURCHASES
FROM [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB]
GROUP BY [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB].Report_Header

UNION ALL

SELECT [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2].Report_Header,
       Sum([JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2].SumOfCASES) AS CASES,
       Sum([JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2].SumOfPurchases) AS PURCHASES
FROM [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2]
GROUP BY [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_Rolling12_SUB2].Report_Header;
```

This may be what you want.  But, it will not combine information under the same header from both tables.  For that, the simplest method is probably a view.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that worked as you noted and then I was able to do a simple query on the union query to combine the info.  When you say the "simplest method is probably a view", is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Place `GROUP BY [JOIN_IB_FREIGHT&PURCHASES_ROLLING12_SUB].Report_Header` under the first query instead of the second.

Comment: Thank Mike!  If I do that, I get all the headers twice, what I was looking to do was show all the headers once, have cases from the first query add to the cases from the second query, same with purchases, for each header item.  This will work for me though, because now all the data is in one place I can I can now do a simple query on the union query to add them.  Thanks!!